# Issue during Redmine installation

Tags: centos, redmine, bitnami

We have a Redmine instance on the centos 7 server with Bitnami. I am getting following error during installation of an another Redmine instance.

**Command Used:**
[root@localhost htdocs]# bundle install --without development test

**Error Message:**
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Hi, could you please give us more info about how are you installing the new instance of redmine?

Comment: If you follow http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall , we are getting issue on step 4 in the current server

Comment: Any luck?? Please give us a solution

Answer (score 0):

The Bitnami installer includes a ready to use Redmine stack, so I assume you're trying to install additional plugins on the vanilla Redmine install.

I suspect that you forgot to load the proper environment variables to use the Bitnami Stack mysql libraries. Go to your install directory (usually /opt/bitnami/redmine) and execute this `source ./use_redmine`

And then follow this instructions https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/#install_plugins

Comment: Basically I have getting the error while installing another Redmine instance on the same server.